# Making Two Vectors Have The Same Number of Elements

Tags: matlab, vector

The title states what I am having trouble with. I have two vectors, t for time, and v for velocity, and I am trying to make them have the same length. Here is a portion of my script:

```
v= v(v<=P/F);

t = t(1:end - length(v));
```

I'll explain what I am doing. I am trying to remove the elements of v that are greater than P/F, which will then change the length of the vector v; and then I would like to remove a sufficient amount of elements from the end of the vector t, so that v and t have the same number of elements. I feel as though I am close to being correct, but I just need a little help

Thank you!

Comment: I think you meant `t = t(1:length(v))`

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to interpolate the unwanted peak values, instead of removing then and squeezing the time vector? Physically its not the best manner, what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you seem to have gotten lost in a brain maze...This is how it's done:

```
inds = v<=P/F;
v = v(inds);
t = t(inds);
```

Comment: So does inds represent the number of elements meeting the condition P/F; and the v(inds) is the elements of v from 1 to inds?

Comment: @Mack 'inds' is a vector with '1' where the condition is met and '0' where the condition isn't met. It selects all elements from 'v' that meet your condition.

Comment: @Mack: jup! indexing with a vector of true/false values is called *logical indexing*. It basically acts as a mask over the vector; select those values of `v` and `t` for which `inds == true`.